# Button height different from background height in Android

Tags: android, button, nine-patch

As the title, in a button I set a resource in the background (a square image).
The problem is that the button is now much higher than the classical buttons, how do I make it as high as the others?

I tried with 9.patch but have the same result...
This is the 9patch file (only the angle is important)
[image]

**Code of the button :**

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonLogIn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="Log In"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

**Code of the resource :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bottonep" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/bottone" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

Comment: Provide some code and more details.

Comment: Have you tried tweaking `android:padding=""` for that `Button` ?

Comment: why i have to put the code? it's only a picture. (now i add the layout)
with the padding i can't know how big is the font size

Answer (score 0):

i've solved with this
the ninepath must be smallest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed_holo_dark" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_holo_dark" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```